# How to input text into this username field

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need help with inputting text into this username textbox.

The html code on the website for this textbox is shown like this.

```
<input type="text" name="username1" maxlength="16" onpaste="return false" 
oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" 
value="" id="input-rounded" class="userpass"
onkeydown="checkField(document.forms[0].username, document.forms[0].username1);" 
onkeyup="checkField(document.forms[0].username, document.forms[0].username1);" 
onchange="checkField(document.forms[0].username, document.forms[0].username1);">
```

I tried the codes below using powershell but it doesnt work. There is still no text appeared on the username textbox.

```
$elements = $IE.document.getElementsByName('username1')
Foreach($element in $elements) {$element.value = $Username}
```

Comment: That is the ugliest input element I have ever seen.

Comment: It is from a bank login website.

Comment: Why aren't you using javascript? I didn't even know powershell could do dom manipulation. Can it?

Comment: Powershell can do dom using internet explorer. I am using powershell to do automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID() instead.

```
$IE.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID('username1').value = $Username
```